# Javascript JQuery only work with out debugger open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used to write js jquery for some case like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.selector', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(id);

    $('#tes').html('it works only with no debugger');
});
```

Lets say I have Table that created dynamically with datatable serverside. So each `.selector` is dynamic. The code above is working fine, But works with and only if debugger is not opened when the document load. If the debugger is open, nothings happen. I know its not a problem for client, but I can't do any debugging. I have looking for the solution anywhere but the most common result I get is their JQuery only works with debugger. Feel free to ask me more if my question is not clear enough.

My data json :

```
{
    "data":[
        [
            1,
            "<a href='javascript:void(0)' data-id='1' class='selector'>Detail<\/a>"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "<a href='javascript:void(0)' data-id='2' class='selector'>Detail<\/a>"
        ],
        [           
            3,
            "<a href='javascript:void(0)' data-id='3' class='selector'>Detail<\/a>"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _nothing happen_. Also, do you have any break point ? Maybe nothing happen because you're stopped at a break point.

Comment: What debugger? The JavaScript one in your browser or some server-side debugger?

Comment: @Nicolas when I click `.selector` the function is not called. The `#tes` will not filled how it supposed to filled. For now I have no break point. The code above exactly how my code is look like.

Comment: @Phil the one bundle in browser

Comment: I update my question. That is my json from datatable serverside. Please take a look if it's helping.

Comment: for dynamic contents usually the clicks are off. If you want to enable click for ```selector``` you have to use ```$('.selector').on("click",function(){<YOUR_CODE>})```

Comment: @Anup I think that is not gonna work. Because the `.selector` is dynamic so I have to select to its parent. What makes it odd is why my code only works only without debugger open.